# How to install java on debian virtual machine

Tags: java, installation, virtual-machine

I am trying to install Java 11 on GCP Debian 9 strech VM using PPA repositories/

I followed the steps, but after `sudo apt install oracle-java11-installer`
I get error code saying package oracle `java11- installer` has no installation candidate.
I even tried java11-installer-local, but it is also not working.

Step 1 : `sudo apt install dirmngr`

Step 2 :

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EA8CACC073C3DB2A
```

Add the following PPA to your Debian system. This PPA contains a package `oracle-java11-installer` having the Java installation script :-

Step 3 : `echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu bionic main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/linuxuprising-java.list`

Step 4 : `sudo apt update`

Step 5 : `sudo apt install oracle-java11-installer`

Step 6 : `sudo apt install oracle-java11-set-default`

Verify Java Version

Step 7 : `java -version`

it keeps giving the error `E: Package 'oracle-java11-installer' has no installation candidate`

Comment: Check [what the PPA contains](https://launchpad.net/~linuxuprising/+archive/ubuntu/java). I see two packages there: `oracle-java11-installer-local` and `oracle-java12-installer`. But not `oracle-java11-installer`. Appently your instructions are outdated. See [these newer instructions](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/06/new-oracle-java-11-installer-for-ubuntu.html).

Comment: what if i ant to install oracle-java11-installer-local, can give me the steps

Comment: See [the new instructions](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/06/new-oracle-java-11-installer-for-ubuntu.html) (<= click the link to see the instructions).

Comment: i am doing it on GCP not on terminal

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this one

```
$sudo apt update
$sudo apt install default-jdk

$java -version

$echo 'deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list

$sudo apt update
$sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
```